# Python - Returning the value if there is an "exact" match?

Tags: python, string, find, any

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']

def findexact(lst):
    i=0
    key = ['a','g','t']
    while i < len(lst):
        if any(item in lst[i] for item in key):
            print lst[i]
        i+=1

findexact(lst)
```

in the above code, the result comes out to be:

```
'a'
'aa'
```

I would like the result to be:

```
'a'
```

What is the right way to use `any()` to get the right result?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Printing `'a'` and "returning True" are not the same thing. Which one do you want?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I was writing the post then I changed the code to print 'a'. I forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match your expected output, you cannot use `set.intersection` as sets are *unordered* so if you get `a` as the first item it is totally by chance , you should make `key` a set and use `in`,iterating over the list returning the first match which will keep the order:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = {'a','g','t'}
    for ele in lst:
        if ele in key:
            return ele
    return False
```

If you want to get all the matches and see the non matches just make key a set and use a loop:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = {'a','g','t'}
    for ele in lst:
        if ele in key:
            print(ele)
        else:
            # do whatever
```

If you want to return a bool based on whether there are any common element use `set.isdisjoint`:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = {'a','g','t'}
    return not key.isdisjoint(lst)
```

If there is at least one match, the function will return True, if not then the sets are disjoint so it will return False.

If you want the index use enumerate:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = {'a','g','t'}
    for ind,ele in enumerate(lst):
        if ele in key:
            return ind, ele
    return False
```

That will return both the element and the index if we have a match, if you just want the index just return `ind`, for no match we simply return False

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of the exact match? If there is just one match in the "lst"

Comment: @niamleeson, enumerate will give you the index

Answer (score 2):

Based on my interpretation of your question, it looks like you want to find which item in `key` is in `lst`. This would be the way to do it:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = ['a','g','t']
    for k in key:
        if k in lst:
            print k
            return k
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do all that indexing.

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = ['a','g','t']
    for item in (set(key) & set(lst)):
        return item
```

Comment: Beat me to it; I was going to say that you shouldn't `print` inside a function unless that's the purpose of the function, or you're debugging.

Comment: Is there a way to use "for item in (set(key) & set(lst))" with if statement? If there is a match, do something.

Comment: Sure - save it and then check it. `myset = (set(key) & set(lst))`, `if myset:...`.

Comment: you don't have to call set twice, `set(key).intersection(lst)`, also why are you looping and then returning?

Comment: ah okay. This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I'd rather use `&` than `intersection()`, and looping over it seemed the simplest way to return the first available item in the `set`.

Comment: calling set on both is actually slower, also sets have no order so just returning a random item seems a bit odd. If there is no match your function also returns None

Comment: I prefer the look of `&`, but it could certainly be changed to `intersection()` if/when performance issues arose. It does return a random item, but the OP's code uses `any()` which implies that order doesn't matter. If it does, `set`s wouldn't work anyway. I'm fine with it returning `None` if there's no match. The question is moderately ambiguous.

Comment: I think the OP does not realise that it is by chance they are getting `a` returned

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use Python's built-in set intersection:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
key = ['a','g','t']

for item in set(lst).intersection(key):
    print item
```

**Output**

```
a
```

Putting that into a function that returns the exact matches:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = ['a','g','t']
    return set(lst).intersect(key)
```

Or into a function that returns `True` if there is at least one exact match:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = ['a','g','t']
    return bool(set(lst).intersect(key))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the set().intersect() with if statement? for example, if there is a match, do something?

Comment: Yes, just do: `if set(lst).intersect(key): print 'exact match!'`

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
def findexact(lst):
    i=0
    key = ['a','g','t']
    for eachItm in lst:
        if eachItm in key:
            print eachItm

findexact(lst)
```

This should do what you trying

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
item in lst[i] for item in key
```

looks for each element of the key **inside** of each element of the list.  And finds 'a' inside of 'a' and inside of 'aa'.  It doesn't find 'g' or 't' inside of any element of the lst.