# Get the index of the exact match from a list

Tags: python, string, indexing, find, match

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']

def findexact(lst):
    i=0
    key = ['a','g','t']
    while i < len(lst):
        if any(item in lst[i] for item in key):
            print i

        i+=1

findexact(lst)
```

in the above code, the result comes out to be:

```
0
3
```

I would like the result to be:

```
0
```

I would like to get the index of the "exact" match. What do I need to do to get the acceptable result?

Comment: Why are you using the same non-working algorithm from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061078/python-returning-the-value-if-there-is-an-exact-match)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `if any(item in lst[i] for item in key):` to this:

```
if any(item == lst[i] for item in key):
```

You were getting multiple results because 'a' is `in` 'aa' but 'a' is not `==` to 'aa'.

Does that give you the behavior you want?

Comment: so simple. i love your answer. im not sure why i didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `in` to `==` and make the test a bit different like follows:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']

def findexact(lst):
    key = ['a','g','t']
    for idx, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if any(item == elem for item in key):
            print idx

findexact(lst)
```

Note here that I'm iterating over `lst` directly and getting the index from enumerate. This is a more pythonic way of doing it than introducing a variable `i` that just keeps track of the index. You can condense this further as the one liners in other answers show.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `index()`. This tells you the index of the given item in the given `list`. If it's not present, it produces an error, which we will catch.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']

def findexact(lst):
    keys = ['a','g','t']
    for key in keys:
        try:
            return lst.index(key)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print findexact(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate with a gen exp,calling next with a default value to catch where you have no common elements:

```
def findexact(lst):
    key = {'a','g','t'}
    return next((ind for ind,ele in enumerate(lst) if ele in key), None)
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
match = findexact(lst)
if match is not None:
  print(match)
0
```

This is `O(n)` as set lookups are `O(1)`, in the worst case we look at every element in lst, for large amounts of data, using list.index or having keys as a list and using `in` is not going to scale well